# How do you match against a defrecord's type in a case statement?

Tags: clojure

Why doesn't `case` work when using an records type?

```
(defrecord Thing [x])
=> myproject.core.Thing

(defn foo [x]
  (case (type x)
    Thing "Thing found!"
    "nope!"))
=> #'myproject.core/foo

(foo (Thing. 123))
=> "nope!"
```

why doesn't this work? Testing the equality directly appears to work:

```
(= (type (Thing. 123)) Thing)
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the docstring for `case`:

```
The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time
literals, and need not be quoted. ... All manner of constant
expressions are acceptable in case, including numbers, strings,
symbols, keywords, and (Clojure) composites thereof.
```

So `Thing` is just a symbol, not a class/type. You can see that is true in this example:

```
dev=> (case (symbol "java.lang.Long")
 #_=>   java.lang.Long "long"
 #_=>   "short")
"long"
dev=> (case (class 1)
 #_=>   java.lang.Long "long"
 #_=>   "short")
"short"
dev=>
```

In that second case, `(class 1)` evaluates to `java.lang.Long` -- an object of type `java.lang.Class` -- but as we can see from the first case, `java.lang.Long` as a test-constant is a `clojure.lang.Symbol`.

Comment: Despite the docs, in ClojureScript, symbols as cases *may* be evaluated, depending on what they seem to be referring to! Therefore, if the algorithm is potentially portable, for general purposes it is more prudent to use "cond" or a protocol or multimethod than to use symbols as the criteria in "case".